# Position fixed doesn't work inside relative position, CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to put div with position:fixed inside div with position:relative.

This is CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: #199eaf;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu-space {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 174px;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 43px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transform: skewY(-10deg);
    width: calc(100% + 100px);
    z-index: 800;
}
```

This for some reason doesn't work as I expect. My div goes inside next div in #wrapper div (See screenshot: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/445294/fb3d41bfb92a0f76d60266ed0ac4f0a9) I can make this work just if I use one of this two solution for .menu-space div

transform: skewY(-10deg) translate(0px, -101px);
or
top: -170px;

But I really don't want to use those minus values. Can someone please help me to find better solution?

This is how menu should look
http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/445297/e799ee584ead6007b9fe16628ccc15bc

and on scroll:
http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/445300/cee6600490bab7e58a479da23ac9974a

Thank you!

Comment: Read: [10.1 Definition of "containing block"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details). What are you trying to achieve? p.s. images are worth millions of words.

Comment: I'm trying to fix this .menu-space in top left corner. If you just take a look at my website and view source for this .menu section, you will see that if you put transform: skewY(-10deg); instead transform: skewY(-10deg) translate(0px, -101px);  menu won't be fixed in top left corner, and I'm confused why because menu should be fixed inside #wrapper div that have position relative. I don't know why this doesn't work.

Comment: Ok well, you cannot expect us to follow a link to your site, I won't. Your question should include a [mcve]. We should be able to understand what your trying to achieve and what issue you are facing by reading your question. What happens when your link changes? Then this question will make absolutely no sense to anyone else. All relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem should be included *in your question*.

Comment: Ok, I add some screenshots, I hope it will be enough to figure out what I'm talking about. I don't know how to explain better.

Comment: I must say, the design of that website is very odd (in other words, non-friendly UX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, transforms happen from the *center* of the element.  Your skew is twisting the element from its center, causing the left side to drop and the right side to rise.

Set `transform-origin: top left` (or 0 0 if you prefer) and you can get rid of the negative top or translate.

```
.menu-space {
   background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
   height: 174px;
   left: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding: 43px;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   transform: skewY(-10deg);
   transform-origin: top left;
   width: calc(100% + 100px);
   z-index: 800;
}
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

Comment: I notice that this property transform-origin: top left; you added and make this work doesn't work in Safari. :( I tried with -webkit-transform-origin: top left;  and   -moz-transform-origin: top left;  but that doesn't fix issue. Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: try `0 0` instead of `top left`.

Comment: You should post a new question for that. Based on caniuse.com, it should work in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is the `transform: skewY(-10deg);`. As per the W3C spec, if `position: fixed;` is used on an element inside an element with a transformation applied to it, the fixed-position element is positioned relative to that transformed element.